# Canny Edge detector in Matlab returns "ant race" image

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use the edge function in Matlab on an image of black and white shock waves. The image that I get from using this function is an "ant race" image. I am wondering if there is a different way to go about finding the edge of the shockwaves. Below is my code:

```
edgeimage = edge(Imagematrix(:,:,45),'Canny');
```

This is the original picture

[image: the original picture]

Imagematrix is a three dimensional 2048x2040x90 matrix.

This is the image I get when I run the edge function

[image: image I get when I run the edge function]

Comment: can you post the original image ?

Comment: implementing canny yourself, you can twist and tweak the parameters. this could provide to be useful.

Comment: @NikolasRieble, I just updated my post with the orignal picture!

Comment: Well, thats how your image looks like. There are not "flat" areas, so everything is edge! I suggest giving edge a 3rd parameter (threshold) and toying with that, see if you get something decent

Comment: @NikolasRieble, It may be helpful to know that the pixels are on a scale of 0-1 (Although i see a few that are around 1.011). What parameters would you suggest I use? I really appreciate any help!

Comment: @LukeSmith when you are working with image processing toolbox, make sure your image is either `uint8` [0-255] or `double` [0-1] !!

Comment: what is your target? do you want to get the outside edges of the whole object?

Comment: @NikolasRieble The target is to get the edges of the shockwaves which are the darker lines going diagonally across the image. The outside is less important

Comment: then i guess the answer provided is already pointing the right directon.

Comment: It is! Thank you to everyone who pitched in and helped! You are all incredibly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You whole image is "non-flat" so edges are everywhere. Try using the 3rd parameter of edge, threshold. Example using your image

```
% ofc this is not your real data, but close
I=imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaVGh.png'); 
edgeimage = edge(I(:,:,1),'Canny',0.22);
imshow(edgeimage)
```

[image]

Play with different values of threshold. You can also play with the `sigma` variable, it defines the size of the kernels

Comment: Also play around with the hysteresis thresholds.  There are two thresholds in Canny that are valid - the low threshold and the high threshold.  Play around with both of those, as well as the size of the Gaussian blur and the window for Non-Maxima Suppression for good results.

Comment: @rayryeng unfortunatedly you canno access all that in MATLABs `edge`

Comment: Are you sure? I took a look at the docs. You can at least play around with the thresholds and blur size. You're right about the NMS though.